Wrinkling on a fluid foundation
I have this problem in fluid mechanics/elasticity and honestly don't know how to start.
A large elastic sheet of bending modulus A overlies a fluid of density $\rho$. Due to external compression, the sheet wrinkles with amplitude $y = a \cos kx$,
where $x$ is a coordinate along the sheet. Explain why wrinkling changes the potential energy of the
fluid by an amount $\rho gy^2/2$, where $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity. Deduce that $k=(\frac{\rho g}{A})^{\frac{1}{4}}$.


This is an energy minimization problem; the sum of the fluid gravitational potential energy and the elastic sheet bending strain energy must be minimized at equilibrium. You can find this reasoning and general strategy from an online search for elastic sheet wrinkling compression wavelength, for instance; example. When in doubt, try searching the internet and literature for keywords.
